# jQuery Timepicker "changeTime" not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, timepicker

I have included jQuery timepicker in my project, and I want to alert some value after a new time is selected/changed from the timepicker element. This is my code.

_form.slim

```
.form-group.col-md-6
      = f.label :start_time, "Start Time *"
      = f.text_field :start_time, class: "form-control timepicker start-time", id: "onselectExample"
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#onselectExample').timepicker();
        $('#onselectExample').on('changeTime', function () {
            alert("Value Changed");
        });

    });
```

The event is not triggering when new value is selected from the timepicker element.

Note: I have also tried the `on.("change",function(){})` event handling.

Comment: Which timepicker library are you using? Can you link to the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Try `change` option

```
function alertChange () {
  alert("Value Changed");  
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#onselectExample').timepicker({ change: alertChange });
}
```

Hope that helps!